# Extract data rows where date equals today minus one or more quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a daterange (SQL server) like the following:

```
UserID, Date
4582, 2012-09-04
4665, 2012-09-05
1251, 2012-06-05
6538, 2011-08-04
7485, 2011-09-05
```

I need to extract data where date equals today minus one or more quarters (e.g. today minus 1 quater, today minus 2 quarters etc.)

In this case the data that should be returned is:

```
UserID, Date
4665, 2012-09-05
1251, 2012-06-05
7485, 2011-09-05
```

Can I create this query using `datediff(quarter,date,getdate())` or do I need to do something different ?

Answer (score 1):

`datediff(quarter,date,getdate())` returns whether the dates are in separate quarters not whether they are exactly a quarter apart, which I think is what you are looking for.

So I would look to find dates that are a multiple of 3 months previously and that also are on the same day of the month.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbaf3/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
    ([UserID] int, [Date] date);

INSERT INTO tablea
    ([UserID], [Date])
VALUES
    (4582, '2012-09-04'),
    (4665, '2012-09-05'),
    (1251, '2012-06-05'),
    (6538, '2011-08-04'),
    (7485, '2011-09-05');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE
    -- Only get dates which are a multiple of 3 months previosuly
    DATEDIFF(mm, [DATE], GETDATE()) % 3 = 0
    -- only get dates that fall on the same day of the month
    AND DAY(GETDATE()) = DAY([Date])
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbaf3/3/0)**:

```
| USERID |       DATE |
-----------------------
|   4665 | 2012-09-05 |
|   1251 | 2012-06-05 |
|   7485 | 2011-09-05 |
```

Comment: @user1519923 no problems, if this is the right answer for you, could you accept my answer as the accepted answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select 
userID, 
`date_column`

from 
table
where `date_column`> DATE_SUB(CURDATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use DATE_SUB

Comment: why cant you use DATE_SUB?
ANd how about DATEDIFF? can you use it?

Comment: It's not a recognized built in function name. I can use DATEDIFF

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
userID, 
`date_column`

from 
table
where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date('date_col')) >= 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server, you can create a list of dates with a recursive query that match the value of today minus one quarter, etc and then get your final list:

```
;with dates (value) as
(
  select cast(getdate() as date)
  union all
  select dateadd(quarter, -1, value)
  from dates
  where dateadd(quarter, -1, value) >= '2010-01-01'
)
select userid, date
from yourtable t
inner join dates d
  on t.date = d.value
```

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/957f0/6)

Result:

```
| USERID |       DATE |
-----------------------
|   4665 | 2012-09-05 |
|   1251 | 2012-06-05 |
|   7485 | 2011-09-05 |
```